# One of the configured repositories failed

Tags: centos, yum

I have searched and cannot find a solution for this error. This occurs when I attempt to run `yum update` or even when I try to install an RPM package.

```
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown), and yum doesn't have enough cached data  
to continue. At this point the only safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to 
work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

The problem seems to reside in the CentOS-Base repo, since it is the only one that is enabled:

```
repo id                 repo name                               status
base/7/x86_64           CentOS-7 - Base                           0
extras/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Extras                         0
updates/7/x86_64        CentOS-7 - Updates                        0
repolist: 0
```

Things that I've tried:

- Using curl to see if the mirrorlist URL is available, returned 200.
- Uncommenting the baseurl of the repo gave me another error: Requested datatype primary not available. After re-commenting the baseurl this new error doensn't go away.
- `yum clean all` , makes the requested datatype error go away.

I would greatly appreciated with any help you could provide on this.